# idiots guide to workflows !!

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

I am looking to build a workflow that is instigated based on the competition of a document to then send the completed document to a folder based on its Reference number i am completely new to workflows and was wondering how easy it would be to do and what platform to complete it on !

Many thanks

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft has built a lot for you. Check out the [Content Organizer](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Configure-the-Content-Organizer-to-route-documents-b0875658-69bc-4f48-addb-e3c5f01f2d9a)